# Sorting a large table with a select box using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a really large table (around 32 columns and 1000+ rows) which I'm trying to filter using a drop down box.

The table takes a relatively standard format (this one has been redacted for simplicity):

```
<div id="SearchResults">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Report Name</th>
<th>xxxxx Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Sales_Report_Week_#</td>
<td>Sales Volume</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The drop down box has already been assembled like so:

```
<select name="Report_Name_Drop" id="id_dropdown"> 
<option>xxxxx1</option>
<option>xxxxx2</option> 
<option>xxxxx3</option>
<option>xxxxx4</option> 
<option>xxxxx5</option> </select>
```

Unfortunately I'm working within a severely locked down sharepoint environement meaning I am unable to use any plug ins. I simply need to hide all rows which do not match the value in the drop down box but I can't for love nor money figure out how!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

James

Comment: It is not clear from your question how the values in the `<select>` options correspond to rows of the table.  What are the `<option>` value attributes set to?  What exactly is the filtering that needs to be done?

Comment: Also, your post talks about "filtering" but the question title uses the word "sorting".  Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Basically I create a set of the values in the filter column, and add those values to the `<select>` dropdown. Then when that dropdown changes I hide/show the relevant rows in the table. This pattern can be extended to include multiple filters as needed, just test all the relevant columns against all the relevent `<select>` elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var vals = {};
        $('tbody tr').each(function(i){
            var t = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
            vals[t] = t;
        });
        $.each(vals, function() {
            $('select').append($('<option value="' + this +'">' + this +'</option>'));
        });
        $('select').change(function() {
            var val= $(this).val();
            if (val != '-') {
              $('tbody tr').each(function(i){
                  if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text() != val) {
                    $(this).hide();
                  } else {
                    $(this).show();
                  }
              });
            } else {
              $('tbody tr').each(function(i){
                  $(this).show();
              });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select><option value="-"> === Filter === </option></select>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Mark</td><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Mark</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Daryl</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Larry</td><td>122</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Kevin</td><td>132</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Larry</td><td>1232</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Kevin</td><td>1432</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was after! Thank you so much. For anyone else trying to make this work in sharepoint I added an ID to the table and specified it in the above code wherever '$('tbody tr')' is referenced making it $('tbody#TABLE ID tr'). Again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing the nature of the filter you're trying to create, I'd generally suggest managing this with data stored in an object or an array of objects (one for each row). This could look something like this:

```
var data = {
    filters: ['filter value 1', 'filter value 2', ...],
    rows: [{name:'row name', week:1, year:2010, sales_volume:4564}, {...}, ...]
}
```

And so...whenever your user picked an index in your select, you could recreate the table by performing a check against the `sales_volume` or `name` or `year` or whatever index. It would look something like this:

```
var selectedFilter = $('#id_dropdown').val();

$.each(data, function(ind, el) {
    if (el.name == selectedFilter)
        //write the row to your table
    else
        return true; //continue to next index
});
```

But without more information, it's difficult to help much beyond general advice.